# ArrayList sort method

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

A friend and I are writing some software (as a side project) and are having trouble with ArrayLists.

We're storing a collection of instances of a custom object (containing a DateTime and two strings) in an ArrayList. Once we've stored all of the entries in the ArrayList, we're sorting them by DateTime. The problem is, that we're having to store of 100,000 instances of the object, which means that the built in sort method is taking a very long time - we clocked it at over an hour, at one point.

The speed of the sort isn't so much of an issue, but I was just wondering whether there was a better way to sort elements in an ArrayList than using the built in sort method. Although I guess not, based on the fact that the built in .net stuff will be highly optimised.

Note: We're using ArrayLists because of the middleware we've chosen to use for generating PDF reports, based on the content of the ArrayList. I guess, if we had the chance to move over to List<> then the sort methods would be better. Or would they?

Edit:

Based on requests for source code, I'll post some. But I'm not sure how much I can provide that isn't obvious.

```
public class DataObject : ICompareable
{
   private DateTime timeStamp;
   private string description;
   private string detail;

   public DataObject (DataTime inTimeStamp, string inDescription,
                      string inDetail)
   {
      this.timeStamp = inTimeStamp;
      this.description = inDescription;
      this.detail = inDetail;
   }

   int IComparable.CompareTo(object that)
   {
       DataObject myThat = (DataObject)that;
       return this._timestamp.CompareTo(myThat._timestamp);
   }
}

 // .... //

ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < database.Packets.Count; i++)
{
  dataList.Add(new DataObject(database.Packet(i).GetTimeStamp(),
               database.Packet(i).GetDescription(),
               database.Packet(i).GetDetail());
}

// ... same as the above, but for other data
// ... types (all parse to strings when pulled
// ... from the database

dataList.Sort();
```

That's about it, largely. We're pulling data from several places in an SQLCEME3.5 database (we're using .net 3.5, so we can't use LINQ), placing them in an ArrayList of objects and using that object ArrayList further down the pipe.

We want to get all the records from multiple places in the database (some are packets, some are strings (prompts), some are other types, all parse down to strings) and sort them all by time stamp. We want all the data interspersed - a packet followed by some string value, followed by some object value, if that's the order that they were stored/raised in.

We have read-only access to the database, so I don't think that using the database, itself to sort them would be a good idea (or even possible). That being said, I am really new to SQL - never used it before this project. Can that be done?

Comment: Would storing things in a database, sort them and then retrieve them be an option?

Comment: 100000 instances should be an extremely fast thing to sort on any reasonable hardware. Even if you used trained mice to move your objects in memory, Java's sort would complete in under a second. Please show the code to see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Show us the class definition. Also, if you are calling `ArrayList.Sort(IComparer)`, show us the `IComparer`. As @dasblinkenlight said, 100,000 items should sort very quickly--in milliseconds. Also, the sort methods are the same. Both `ArrayList` and `List<T>` use an array as the backing store, and a call to the `Sort` method ends up calling `Array.Sort`.

Comment: Source code (and expanded description) added.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you've posted. And you're certain that the sort itself is taking all the time? Or is perhaps loading from the database taking time? Have you used `Stopwatch` to time *just the sort*? By the way, you don't need `int IComparable.CompareTo`. You can write `public int CompareTo`.

Comment: I'll take a look at the CompareTo method (partner wrote that). I've used break points to confirm that it's the Sort() function that's taking a long time - the database pulls take, on average 15-20 seconds and we're talking about a lead time 40-45 minutes for the Sort(). I'll go back and check with a stop watch, though.

Comment: I implemented a StopWatch (as per the advice of @JimMischel), the sort method did, indeed take less than half a second. After putting stop watches around some of the other code that comes later on - mostly the  export to PDF function. Turns out it's that that's slowing down the whole process. I was wrong, and admit it.

Answer (score 1):

Either your problem is somewhere else, or the code you posted isn't an accurate representation of what's running. Or, perhaps, your data is in a really bad order that causes Sort to exhibit worst case behavior. I find the last pretty unlikely.

Here's my test program that adds 100,000 of your `DataObject` instances to an `ArrayList` and then calls `Sort`. It executes in less than 50 milliseconds on my machine.

Note that this is .NET 4.5, not 3.5. However, I can't imagine that the sort is so horribly broken in the earlier version.

```
public class DataObject : IComparable
{
    private DateTime timeStamp;
    private string description;
    private string detail;

    public DataObject(DateTime inTimeStamp, string inDescription,
                       string inDetail)
    {
        this.timeStamp = inTimeStamp;
        this.description = inDescription;
        this.detail = inDetail;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object that)
    {
        DataObject myThat = (DataObject)that;
        return this.timeStamp.CompareTo(myThat.timeStamp);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create an ArrayList with DataObject items.
        const int NumItems = 100000;

        // The items get random time stamps within the last year
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime baseDate = endDate.AddYears(-1);
        int secondsRange = (int)((endDate - baseDate).TotalSeconds);
        Random rnd = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} items to list.", NumItems);
        ArrayList dataList = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumItems; ++i)
        {
            DateTime ts = baseDate.AddSeconds(rnd.Next());
            DataObject item = new DataObject(ts, "Foo", "bar");
            dataList.Add(item);
        }
        Console.Write("Sorting list...");
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        dataList.Sort();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("done!");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added an additional comment to my question, following a weekend of diagnostics

Answer (score 1):

If your data is TimeStamp then this is an implementation.

Sort on 100,000 rows in 200 milliseconds.
And it has to do a lot of sorting.
Something is wrong in your code.

```
namespace TimeStamp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = "data source=... size=4096";
            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {            
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT [timestamp], [value] FROM [TimeStmp] Order By [timestamp] desc";
                SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    // al.Add(new ValueWithTimeStamp(rdr.GetSqlBinary(0), rdr.GetString(1)));
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)  al.Add(new ValueWithTimeStamp(rdr.GetSqlBinary(0), rdr.GetString(1)));
                    // table has 10 rows so this is 100,000 and the select is desc to is has to so a lot of sorting
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Debug.WriteLine(((ValueWithTimeStamp)al[i]).TimeStampUInt64.ToString());
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            al.Sort();
            sw.Stop();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) Debug.WriteLine(((ValueWithTimeStamp)al[i]).TimeStampUInt64.ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        }
    }
    public struct ValueWithTimeStamp: IComparable
    {
        private UInt64 timeStampUInt64;
        private string value;
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return -1;
            if (!(obj is ValueWithTimeStamp)) return -1;
            ValueWithTimeStamp comp = (ValueWithTimeStamp)obj;
            return this.TimeStampUInt64.CompareTo(comp.TimeStampUInt64);
        }
        public UInt64 TimeStampUInt64 { get { return timeStampUInt64; } }
        public string Value { get { return value; } }
        public ValueWithTimeStamp(System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary TimeStamp, string Value)
        {
            // using UInt64 for timeStampUInt64  as it implements CompareTo and is something you can read
            timeStampUInt64 = BitConverter.ToUInt64(TimeStamp.Value,0);
            value = Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added an additional comment to my question, following a weekend of diagnostics